# What is 'conceptually equal' ('is-equal' module from npm) vs '==='/'=='. JavaScript. Objects comparison.

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparison-operators

I'm sorry to ask so simple question, but hope, it will help someone too.

Playing around with 'mjackson/expect' found that toEqual((value, [message]) function uses 'is-equal' module for comparison.

What is the point of using such library and what is 'conceptually equal', as told on npm page of module, if we can use strict comparison '===', or simple '=='?

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-equal)

Comment: Try any of the examples of the [isequal documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-equal) with `===`. For example `/a/===/a/`. You'll see.

Comment: Two objects are compared by their references. That is why neither `===` nor `==` is useful for tests involving objects.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I've tried it. Just thought, maybe there is something else  behind the scenes, that I need to know using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strict or loose comparison operators (the `===` and `==` respectively) are both useless if you want to compare object or arrays. This module lets you compare things like arrays and objects easily.

For example this is all true:

```
1 == 1
1 === 1
'abc' == 'abc'
'abc' === 'abc'
true == true
true === true
null == null
null === null
```

but this will always be false in JavaScript:

```
[1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3] === [1, 2, 3]
{a: 1, b: 2} == {a: 1, b: 2}
{a: 1, b: 2} === {a: 1, b: 2}
/.*/ == /.*/
/.*/ === /.*/
new Date('2017') == new Date('2017')
new Date('2017') === new Date('2017')
```

and you often need to compare one object with another, especially in unit tests. With the `==` and `===` operators you cannot compare arrays or objects with some expected values, but with `is-equal` you can compare them with ease.

But when you use `let equal = require('is-equal');` - this is all true:

```
equal(1, 1)
equal('abc', 'abc')
equal(true, true)
equal(null, null)
equal([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
eqial({a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 1, b: 2})
equal(/.*/, /.*/)
equal(new Date('2017'), new Date('2017'))
```

and you don't need to care about the difference in comparisons of different types in JavaScript.